# Opening a French bank account in France for a French/USA dual citizen living in the USA

Tags: banking

I have some money coming in from the sale of my mother's apartment in France. The notaire tells me the transfer has to be direct bank to bank, which will be expensive as I live in the US. I was planing to use Transferwise. So I will need to have a bank account in France. I do not reside in France and have no bank account there. I have US citizenship and am registered at the French consulate in the US. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do it without a French address, unless you have a proxy address (for example Science Accueil acts as a proxy address for new arrivals, but only before they sign rental agreements). And they require endorsement by your university / employer, so I don't think you can do this 'just because', unfortunately.

Comment: Follow up: difficult, not impossible. Very, very difficult from outside Europe. More info here: http://www.french-property.com/guides/france/finance-taxation/banking/opening-an-account/#3.1. -- You appear to need an internet bank without a residency requirement. I think you have to contact the bank for more information.